# How do I replace a character in a string with another character in Python?

Tags: python, string, replace

I want to replace every character that isn't "i" in the string "aeiou" with a "!"

I wrote:

```
def changeWord(word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter != "i":
            word.replace(letter,"!")
    return word
```

This just returns the original. How can I return "!!i!!"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Strings in Python are immutable, so you cannot change them in place. Check out the [documentation of str.replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.replace#str.replace):

> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the 
>   optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

So to make it work, do this:

```
def changeWord(word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter != "i":
            word = word.replace(letter,"!")
    return word
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Should've realized that. Thank you!

Comment: While this'll work, it's worst-case `O(len(word)^2)`.  Something like `''.join('!' if c != 'i' else c for c in word)` would be more efficient for long strings.

Comment: This is an O(n^2) algorithm… It's not wrong, just inefficient

Answer (score 8):

Regular expressions are pretty powerful for this kind of thing. This replaces any character that isn't an "i" with "!"

```
import re
str = "aieou"
print re.sub('[^i]', '!', str)
```

returns:

```
!!i!!
```

Answer (score 3):

something like this using `split()` and `join()`:

```
In [4]: strs="aeiou"

In [5]: "i".join("!"*len(x) for x in strs.split("i"))
Out[5]: '!!i!!'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, as a one-liner:

```
def changeWord(word):
    return ''.join(c if c == 'i' else '!' for c in word)
```

The answer can be concisely expressed using a generator, there's no need to use regular expressions or loops in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody seems to give any love to [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate):

```
In [25]: chars = "!"*105 + 'i' + "!"*150

In [26]: 'aeiou'.translate(chars)
Out[26]: '!!i!!'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @RocketDonkey: I must admit though, that this would be inefficient for small translations in small inputs. It works here to avoid a `str.join` and because there is a LOT of translation :)

Comment: Haha, well it is still a cool a solution - I'm sure someone will get use out of it.

Answer (score 0):

> Generally in python string are immutable that means it can't be changed
>   after its creation. So we have to convert string into mutable and that can be possible using list as it is mutable.

**string="Love"**

```
editable = list(string)
editable[2]='s'
string=''.join(editable)
```

**output:Lose**